# Which Flash Application?

Tags: flash

Which flash application or software did they use to create the smooth flash flow of objects?

http://www.edynamic.net/

Thanks,
Kris

Answer (score 0):

The only Flash on that page is the animated header. That was probably made in, well, Flash.